# Simple TCP client with aleph

Tags: asynchronous, tcp, clojure, aleph

I am trying to connect TCP server, whose code I can't control, via a simple asynchronous client (socket needs to remain open).

The communication is via byte-arrays and I have some custom functions to create and parse the various byte-arrays to send to this server. So I don't require any encoding or decoding via gloss. But I do need a non blocking but connected request-response mechanism.

Aleph looks great but I'm stuck trying to implement the TCP client for my usecase. So far I have the following:

```
    (:require [manifold.deferred :as d]
              [manifold.stream :as s]
              [aleph.tcp :as tcp])
             

    (def aleph-client (atom nil)) 

    ;store my initial connection into the atom
    (reset! aleph-client @(tcp/client {:host (:HOST CONFIG) :port (:PORT CONFIG)}))

    (defn msg! 
      "A very simple request response method"
      [ bytebuf ]
       (d/let-flow [status (s/put! @aleph-client (.array bytebuf))
                    reply  @(s/take! @aleph-client)]
                 reply))
```

In the above code, I'm able to send the correct and expected byte-array to the server and I receive the response too. However I'm unable to take and format the message correctly. I always see the following :

```
(msg! my-bytes)
=> #object["[B" 0x7ad08644 "[B@7ad08644"]

;I seem to be getting a byte-buffer somehow but the byte array length
;is simply wrong for longer messages.
(alength (byte-buffer (msg! my-bytes)))
=>39
```

And I have no idea what to do next here. In particular:

- How to receive the bytebuffer response?
- Is there an elegant way to use the wrap-duplex-stream my my own custom bytebuffer creation and decoding ?
- How to connect the put and the take properly ?
- What is this mysterious response when I do the put and take separately ?
- The bytebuffer I received at the end is indeed the response I expected. At least a part of it. Some of the message is lost somewhere and I can see it upon a successive take! call. Why is this ?
- How to use buffers to put in and take larger messages ?

Would appreciate any help from Aleph and Manifold gurus.

Comment: `take!` returns the object that you need but `let-flow` wraps it in a deferred. You gotta `@` the result of `msg!`.

Comment: Thanks yes when I defer it the <<>> brackets get removed and I get :  #object["[B" 0x7ad08644 "[B@7ad08644"] . I have been able to wrap it with (byte-array @(s/take! @aleph-client)) and it sort of works. I say 'sort of' because sometimes the byte array doesn't capture the entire message. 

So I'm clearly doing something not quite right.

Comment: My guess would be that the body is chunked in some way and that you'd be better off using `byte-streams` to create a single byte array from the response. The docs on Aleph give an example: https://github.com/clj-commons/aleph#http